# How to pass dynamic array from ENV to a docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

We currently load ips from src/main/resources/application.properties as a Map<String, List>

> ```
> server:
>   config:
>     ips:
>       - 10.10.10.10
>       - 10.10.10.11
>       - 10.10.10.12
>       - 10.10.10.13
> ```

If I have to pass this from the ENV for a docker container, how should I do it

Comment: wait, can you clarify? Are you trying to pass it to the docker container as an environment variable? It sounds quite confusing the way you describe it in the question, please provide more details

Comment: if you want to pass it as a environment variable to a docker container, you could use the -e option, `-e SERVER_CONFIG_IPS=10.10.10.10,10.10.10.11` or if in docker compose pass it using the environment attribute similarly `SERVER_CONFIG_IPS=10.10.10.10,10.10.10.11`

Comment: Are you using [tag:docker-compose]? Or [tag:kubernetes]? Or manually like `docker run ...`?

Comment: The Spring Boot documentation chapter on [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) covers most of the possible options.  Bind-mounting a configuration file into the container is an option.  If you want to use environment variables, experimenting with it outside a container might be easier, and then porting your results into Docker syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
server:
  config:
    ips:
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 10.10.10.11
      - 10.10.10.12
      - 10.10.10.13
```

Is equivalent to

```yaml
server:
  config:
    ips: ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11", "10.10.10.12", "10.10.10.13"]
```

It seems you are using spring... so perhaps you could do

```yaml
server:
  config:
    ips: [${SERVER_IPS}]
```

Then set an environment variable

```
SERVER_IPS="10.10.10.10","10.10.10.11","10.10.10.12","10.10.10.13"
```

In this instance I don't think you need the quotes (each value contains at least one non-numeric character, values don't contain commas) so you can likely do

```
SERVER_IPS=10.10.10.10,10.10.10.11,10.10.10.12,10.10.10.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a colon (or separator char of your preference) separated value list to send it in a single env variable and then just split it by separator on the receiver end.

```
env:
  name: IP_LIST
  value: "10.10.10.10;10.10.10.11;10.10.10.12;10.10.10.13"
```